# How do i show client side validation correct using textboxfor and validationmessagefor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem showing my validation correct.

I have the following code in my client.

```
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "MyId", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Name", @class = "valid" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
```

My model contains the users name. So when it is displyed it allready says ex "Micheal" or whatever. But somehow my validation does'nt pick that up. It will still show the message unless i type in something else.

```
my model is a simple model containing [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

the problem as i can see is that the standard html class for textboxfor is

[Picture of html class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTP9h.png)

This is my form

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UserConfirmed", "Login", Model, FormMethod.Post))
    {

    <div class="col-padding">
        <p class="bold-text green">@SharedLocalizer["LabelConfirmUser"]</p>

        <p class="bold-text green userName">@Model.Name</p>

        <a class="btn space-xs-up" onclick="ChangeUser()">@SharedLocalizer["LabelChangeUser"]</a>
        @*<a class="btn space-xs-up" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Login")">@SharedLocalizer["LabelCancel"]</a>*@

        @*<a class="btn space-xs-up pull-right login" type="submit" value="Login">@SharedLocalizer["LabelConfirm"]</a>*@
        <input class="btn space-xs-up pull-right login" value="@SharedLocalizer["LabelConfirm"]" type="submit" />
        <div id="TypeNewUserName" class="field-group" style="display:none">
            <label class="text-green">@SharedLocalizer["LabelNewUser"]</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "MyId", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Name"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change @required to required inside @html.TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "MyId", required = "required", @placeholder = "Name"})
```